# Код словаря, который будет одинаково хорошо работать на Python 2.x и 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, кроссплатформенность

В Python 3.x с [PEP 3106: Dictionary Views](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) поменялось поведение словарей.

У меня есть свой класс, производный от `dict`, похожий по поведению на `collections.OrderedDict`, но отличающийся от него. В любом случае, у класса «под капотом» есть список `self._ordering`. Вот фрагмент, отражающий основную суть:

```
class TimestampingDict(dict):
    """
    An ordered dictionary, tracking item update times.
    Least recently updated items are returned first.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._ordering = []
        super(TimestampingDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        _timestamp, value = super(TimestampingDict, self).__getitem__(key)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            # TODO: Speed this up with key->order_idx mapping?
            self._ordering.remove(key)
        super(TimestampingDict, self).__setitem__(key, (datetime.now(), value))
        self._ordering.append(key)

    def __delitem__(self):
        self._ordering.remove(key)
        super(TimestampingDict, self).__delitem__(key)

    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self._ordering:
            yield key
```

Хочется написать такой код, который будет одновременно одинаково хорошо работать и для 2.6+ и 3.x, ведя для каждой версии максимально «нативно.»

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как бы это сделать покрасивее, максимально DRY?

Идея запихать этот класс в отдельное яйцо-пакет и использовать setup.py с вызовом 2to3 мне откровенно не нравится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему просто не унаследоваться от `OrderDict`? Тогда уж это точно будет масимально DRY.

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict

class TimestampingDict(OrderedDict):
    """
    An ordered dictionary, tracking item update times.
    Least recently updated items are returned first.

    >>> d = TimestampingDict()
    >>> d['c'] = 1
    >>> d['a'] = 2
    >>> d['z'] = 3
    >>> d['g'] = 4
    >>> d['a'] = 5

    >>> for i in d.items(): print('%s = %s' % i)
    a = 5
    g = 4
    z = 3
    c = 1

    >>> d.timestamp('z').__class__
    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
    """

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(TimestampingDict, self).__getitem__(key)[1]

    def timestamp(self, key):
        return super(TimestampingDict, self).__getitem__(key)[0]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self: del self[key]
        super(TimestampingDict, self).__setitem__(key, (datetime.now(), value))

    # для использования принципа LIFO, согласно документации класса
    def __iter__(self):
        it = super(TimestampingDict, self).__iter__()
        return reversed(list(it))
```